# Shuffle, merger and fetcher errors when processing large files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, out-of-memory, shuffle

I am running a word-count like mapreduce job processing 200 files of 1Gb each. I am running the job on a hadoop cluster comprising 4 datanodes (2cpu each) with 8Gb of memory and about 200G of space. I have tried various configurations options but every time my job fails, with either InMemory Shuffle, OnDisk Shuffle, InMemory merger, OnDisk Merger, or Fetcher errors.

The size of the mapper output is comparable to the size of the input files, therefore , in order to minimise the mapper output size I am using the BZip2 compression for the mapreduce output. However even with a compressed map output I still get errors in the reducer phase. I use 4 reducers. Thus I have tried various configurations of the hadoop cluster:

The standard configuration of the cluster was:

```
    Default virtual memory for a job's map-task      3328 Mb
    Default virtual memory for a job's reduce-task  6656 Mb
    Map-side sort buffer memory 205 Mb
    Mapreduce Log Dir Prefix    /var/log/hadoop-mapreduce
    Mapreduce PID Dir Prefix    /var/run/hadoop-mapreduce
    yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb   6656
    mapreduce.admin.map.child.java.opts -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=TRUE -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN
    mapreduce.admin.reduce.child.java.opts  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN
    mapreduce.admin.user.env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -d32 -version &> /dev/null;if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo Linux-i386-32; else echo Linux-amd64-64;fi`
    mapreduce.am.max-attempts   2
    mapreduce.application.classpath $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
    mapreduce.cluster.administrators    hadoop
    mapreduce.framework.name    yarn
 mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps   0.05
    mapreduce.jobhistory.address    ip-XXXX.compute.internal:10020
    mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir   /mr-history/done
    mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir  /mr-history/tmp
    mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address ip-XXXX.compute.internal:19888
    mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx2662m
    mapreduce.map.log.level INFO
    mapreduce.map.output.compress   true
    mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent    0.7
    mapreduce.map.speculative   false
    mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress  true
    mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type BLOCK
    mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent   0.0
    mapreduce.reduce.java.opts  -Xmx5325m
    mapreduce.reduce.log.level  INFO
    mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent 0.7
    mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent  0.66
    mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies 30
    mapreduce.reduce.speculative    false
    mapreduce.shuffle.port  13562
    mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor   100
    mapreduce.task.timeout  300000
    yarn.app.mapreduce.am.admin-command-opts    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN
    yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts  -Xmx5325m
    yarn.app.mapreduce.am.log.level INFO
    yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir   /user
    mapreduce.map.maxattempts       4
    mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts        4
```

This configuration gave me the following error:

```
14/05/16 20:20:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 3%
14/05/16 20:27:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
14/05/16 20:27:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1399989158376_0049_r_000000_0,      Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in InMemoryMerger - Thread to merge in-memory shuffled map-outputs
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
 Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1399989158376_0049_r_000000_0/map_2038.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getInputFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl$InMemoryMerger.merge(MergeManagerImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeThread.run(MergeThread.java:94)
```

Then I've tried changing various options, hopping to reduce the load during the shuffle phase, however I got the same error.

```
mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies     5
mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor   10
```

or

```
mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies     10
mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor   20
```

Then I realised that the tmp files on my data node were non existing and therefore all the merging and shuffling was happening in memory. Therefore I've manually added on each datanode. 
I've kept the initial configuration but increased the time delay before the reducer starts in order to limit the load on the datanode.

```
mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps 0.7
```

I've also tried increasing the io.sort.mb:

```
mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb from 205 to 512.
```

However now I get the following onDisk error:

```
14/05/26 12:17:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 62% reduce 21%
14/05/26 12:20:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1400958508328_0021_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in OnDiskMerger - Thread to merge on-disk map-outputs
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/eoc21/appcache/application_1400958508328_0021/output/attempt_1400958508328_0021_r_000000_0/map_590.out
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl$OnDiskMerger.merge(MergeManagerImpl.java:536)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeThread.run(MergeThread.java:94)
```

The reducer dropped down to 0% and when it got back to 17% I got the following error:

```
14/05/26 12:32:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1400958508328_0021_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#22
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1400958508328_0021_r_000000_1/map_1015.out
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getInputFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.OnDiskMapOutput.<init>(OnDiskMapOutput.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.reserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyMapOutput(Fetcher.java:411)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:165)
```

I read around and it seems that "Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1400958508328_0021_r_000000_1/map_1015.out" is correlated to not having enough space on the node for the spill. However I checked the data node and it seems that there is enough space:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1       40G   22G   18G  56% /
none            3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdj      1008G  758G  199G  80% /hadoop/hdfs/data
```

So not sure what to try anymore. Is the cluster too small for processing such jobs? Do I require more space on the datanodes? Is there a way to find an optimum configuration for the job on hadoop? Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of four things I know if, most likely being the point you made in your question about disk space, or a similar problem - inodes:

- Files being deleted by another process (unlikely, unless you remember doing this yourself)
- Disk error (unlikely)
- Not enough disk space
- Not enough inodes (run `df -i`)

Even if you run `df -h` and `df -i` before/after the job, you don't know how much is being eaten and cleaned away *during* the job.  So while your job is running, suggest watching these numbers / log them to a file / graph them / etc.  E.g.

```
watch "df -h && df -i"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify some temp directories to store the intermediate map and reduce output.
May be you have not specified any temp directories so it could not find any valid directory to store the intermediate data.
You can do it by editing **mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
  <value>/temp1,/temp2,/temp3</value>
</property>
```

Comma-separated list of paths on the local filesystem where temporary MapReduce data is written. Multiple paths help spread disk i/o.

After specifying these temp directories it will store intermediate map and reduce output by choosing the temp directories in any of the below ways

**random**: In this case, the intermediate data for reduce tasks is stored at a data location chosen at random.

**max**: In this case, the intermediate data for reduce tasks is stored at a data location with the most available space.

**roundrobin**: In this case, the mappers and reducers pick disks through round-robin scheduling for storing intermediate data at the job level within the number of local disks. The job ID is used to create unique sub directories on the local disks to store the intermediate data for each job.

you can set this property in **mapred-site.xml**
example

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.local.dir.locator</name>
  <value>max</value>
</property>
```

By default in hadoop it is roundrobin

Answer (score 1):

"mapreduce.cluster.local.dir" (Old deprecated name: mapred.local.dir) specified in the mapred-site.xml.